# Java best way to set many object field values to null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an object with so many fields, lets say 25 to 50 fields.

Now, I want to reset most of the fields. Like only 5 values will be retained.

If I code them manually, that will be setting those 20 to 45 values to null... and I think this is not a good idea.

This object is already stored in DB (mongo), and I would like to reset most of the field values of this object (document) and then update in DB.

I am thinking of creating a new object (not saved in DB), and copy the bean null properties to the original one to set those fields to null.

I am not sure what is the best way to do this using Java 8.

I just want to reset an existing document/record's fields (specific fields but many), and then update the document/record in DB.

TIA

Comment: Why not a default of null for these fields, then copy the fields you want to store into a new instance?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? Which objects are involved in the API handling of the data?  BeanUtils.copyProperties might come in handy assuming you've got a model and a DTO.

Comment: You could do it the other way round: update the DB first, then update the object from it, which will propagate nulls *or* whatever else is in there.

Comment: creating a new object means all field are null then set not null field and save in database..

Comment: Thanks for the ideas :)